# UITableView Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

I have declared a `UITableView` `tableView` with a getter/setter

I want to use this tableView asynchronously

```
await Task.Run (() => getResult ()
```

inside the `getResult` method, I try to access the `tableView` on the main thread

```
InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            tableView.Hidden = false;
        });
```

This results in a

> Null Reference Exception

How can I access the tableView asynchronously without getting a null reference exception. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Generally you want to ensure your idea runs _single-threaded_ before attempting to use _multiple threads_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `tableView` before you can reference it.  A getter/setter will not automatically initialize it for you.  For example, in your constructor you could

```
tableView = new UITableView();
```

Comment: How would I initialize `tableView?`?